# Size of unknown container, vector or array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I try to build a template function that gets 2 iterators(`begin` and `end`) of either a `vector` or an `array`(this must be unknown container passed to function).

1. I want that the function will check for the size of the container passed to it.
   My problems are: if `begin iterator` equals `end iterator` does it mean 0 or 1 elements inside container?
   How can I decalare some universal size type ?
2. If I want to sort the unknown container by passing iterators to sort function is that becomes a problem? I have some feeling that it won't work.

This is my draft of the template function:

```
    template<class P, class T>
    T my_func(P beg, P end)
    {
       typedef typename ??? container_size;
       if (beg == end)//first problem to determine if contains 0 or 1 
                         elements 

       throw domain_error("some message if 0 elements");

       sort(beg, end);// scond problem

    }
```

Comment: [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance). `begin == end` <=> `size == std::distance(begin, end) == 0`.

Comment: ```begin``` being equal to ```end``` depicts that the container is empty

Comment: C++ standard library iterators always use the scheme where the begin iterator is inclusive and the end iterator is exclusive (refers to one-past-the-end).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. I want that the function will check for the size of the container passed to it. My problems are: if begin iterator equals end iterator does it mean 0 or 1 elements inside container? How can I decalare some universal size type ?

You should use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) for that.

> 2. If I want to sort the unknown container by passing iterators to sort function is that becomes a problem? I have some feeling that it won't work.

It would work, provided the iterators are [RandomAccessIterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) and the value type is [swappable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ValueSwappable)

---

So, your code could be:

```
template<class P, class T>
T my_func(P first, P last)
{
   if(first == last) // No elements within the range
        throw domain_error("some message if 0 elements");

   //Number of Elements within the range
   auto container_size = std::distance(first, last);

   std::sort(first, last);

   return ...;
}
```

If my guess is correct, that the template parameter `T` is supposed to be the value type of the iterator, you can obtain it using [`std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits)

Comment: This is a short and precise and reliable answer. I'd like to see more of that kind. Excellent.

Comment: @WhiZTiM If the container is not sequential inside the memory, how does the distance function knows how many bytes is every element inside the container?

Comment: @axcelenator `distance` will try something like `for(; first != last; first++) n++;`

Comment: @PasserBy But without know if type of hop is `int` or `float` how much the increment is authentic?

Comment: @axcelenator iterators abstract away `operator++` for you so that the increment is always valid, this is the whole point of iterators.

Comment: @axcelenator, 1 of 2: C++ concept of an iterator is anything that abstract away the process of accessing elements, one after the other in a container. So, its up to you, the implementer of the container to implement it how you want to. For Sequential and Contiguous containers, its most likely going to be a simple pointer. For other types of data structures, its definitely going to be a little more than incrementing a pointer....

Comment: @axcelenator. 2 of 2: If you look at `std::distance`, it would give you the number of elements in the data structure in `O(1)` if the iterator is *RandomAccess*, otherwise, it would require incrementing the first argument until the last has been reached; which means making the iterator do "whatever work" is necessary (abstracted away by `operator++`) to go the next element until the last has been reached.